# using RtlCompareString to compare user data crashes OS

Tags: c++, kernel, minifilter

I have the following code which is responsible to receive and send data between my mini-filter driver and user-mode:

```
NTSTATUS MiniSendRecv(PVOID portcookie, PVOID InputBuffer, ULONG InputBufferLength, PVOID OutputBuffer, ULONG OutputBufferLength, PULONG RetLength) {
    PCHAR msg = "Hi User";
    PCHAR userData = (PCHAR)InputBuffer;
    DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "User said: %d:%s\n", strlen(userData), userData);
    DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Before comparing strings\n");
    if (RtlCompareString(userData, (PCHAR)"status=stop", TRUE) == 0) {
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "stop requested\n");
    }
    //if((PCHAR)InputBuffer.contains("status=stopservice"))

    if (strlen(msg) > OutputBufferLength) {

        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "message length too big\n");
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }
    strncpy((PCHAR)OutputBuffer, msg, 500);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

WinDBG output:

```
User said: 11:status=stop
Before comparing strings
KDTARGET: Refreshing KD connection

*** Fatal System Error: 0x0000003b
                       (0x00000000C0000005,0xFFFFF8046D001E82,0xFFFF8580E9924C20,0x0000000000000000)

Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)

A fatal system error has occurred.
Debugger entered on first try; Bugcheck callbacks have not been invoked.

A fatal system error has occurred.

nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus:
fffff804`6cdffc70 cc              int     3
```

As you can see the data is received just fine, but as soon as it hit `RtlCompareString`, the driver crashes causing the OS to crash as well.

Also prior to using `PCHAR userData`, I was doing `if (RtlCompareString((PCHAR)InputBuffer, (PCHAR)"status=stop", TRUE) == 0)` but that didn't do any good as well.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? when I call `RtlCompareString` against OutputBuffer, it works just fine.

Comment: `0x00000000C0000005` looks like the error code for an Access Violation, which happens when accessing invalid memory. My guess is `InputBuffer` is NOT a **null-terminated** string (hence why `InputBufferLength` is provided), so `strlen()`, `DbgPrintEx()` and `RtlCompareString()` may be trying to read past the end of the data into surrounding memory.

Comment: Are you sure all your (received) data is '\0' terminated? The arguments don't have length fields for nothing. (You could even use that info to check the length of the input against the length of your command first to avoid having to check the full content of the strings in most cases). In any case, check in your debugger what the actual memory looks like if there is no '\0' in your memory that might be the problem. Maybe using string_view on the buffers could let you use more standard C++ in the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RtlCompareString` compares *counted strings*. What you have are null terminated strings. Just use the regular `strcmp` function, or since you seem to be trying to do a case insensitive string comparison you could try the non-standard `_stricmp` function.

Comment: That explains a lot, the length parameters kind of gave that away :)

Comment: You might want to explain what a "counted string" means.

Comment: @John thanks, since I am new to driver development, in an article I read that you cannot read C runtime libraries, so I didn't try strstr/strcmp and etc. but this worked thanks

Comment: @hashy I noticed in your code that you are using `strlen` and `strncpy` so I assumed the C runtime was available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I always try to implement in terms of standard C++ i.o. winapi calls). string_view is a nice lightweight class to make views on buffers which has hardly any overhead but gives you things like a compare function.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

NTSTATUS MiniSendRecv(PVOID portcookie, PVOID InputBuffer, ULONG InputBufferLength, PVOID OutputBuffer, ULONG OutputBufferLength, PULONG RetLength)
{
    // you can make msg static it will not vary from call to call
    static const std::string_view msg{ "Hi User" };

    // create a string_view on the input, using the passed input length
    const std::string_view input{ static_cast<const char*>(InputBuffer), static_cast<std::size_t>(InputBufferLength) };

    // and now you can just use string_view compare instead of awkward win api call
    if (msg == input)
    {
        std::cout << "messages are equal\n";
    }

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

int main()
{
    std::array hi_buffer{ 'H','i',' ','U','s','e','r' }; // Note : NO trailing '\0` in hi_buffer
    std::array<char, 16> output_buffer;
    ULONG ret_buffer_size{ 0ul };

    MiniSendRecv
    (
        nullptr,
        static_cast<PVOID>(hi_buffer.data()), hi_buffer.size(),
        static_cast<PVOID>(output_buffer.data()), output_buffer.size(),
        &ret_buffer_size
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `MiniSendRecv()` is not making the same comparisons that the OP's code is making, and it is not writing any output data. Also, the `static_cast`s in your `main()` are unnecessary.